# Convert list of string into comma separated 2D NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset like the following:

```
0000000000000001,0
0000000000000010,0
0000000000000011,1
0000000000000100,1
0000000000000101,1
0000000000000110,0
0000000000000111,1
0000000000001000,0
0000000000001001,0
.
.
.
```

I want to convert the first column from each row to be a comma seperated something like this:

From `0000000000000001,0` to `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0`

The following code has a small issue: `full_data` is not 2D numpy of integers, yet it is 1D of string. I am not sure how to fix that. Any hint is appreciated.

```
data = []
my_data = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', delimiter=',',  dtype='str')[:,0]
for i in my_data:
    x= np.asarray(i)
    data.append(x.tolist())

full_data = np.asarray(data)
```

Thank you

Comment: Just split the first entry in the array and then append the second entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
import numpy as np

data = []
my_data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',',  dtype='str')

data = [list(i) + [j] for i, j in my_data]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0']
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great. We can also `np.asarray(data).astype(np.int)` to make it integer list which is what I want. Again, thank you.